# How to disable automatic update of text layers in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How do I disable the automatic update of text layers when I open a .psd document?
The problem is that when I open big .psd files, this update lasts very long and wastes me a lot of time.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design!  Are you opening PSDs that were created in an older version of Photoshop?

Comment: Automatic update? Where? If I open a PSD with old text I'm asked if I want to update it. I can always choose "no". There's no "auto update" for text layers that I'm aware of.

Comment: @Farray I am opening in Windows 7 psd files that are made in Mac OS...

Comment: @Scott there should be a checkbox with something like "never ask again" that I may have checked accidentally...

Comment: @NeS If you remember checking a checkbox like that, try trashing your PS preferences.

Comment: Wait.. you're switching platforms? There's little you can do then. The best solution would be to have the **exact opentype fonts** on both platforms. So that each typeface is read as it's own. If you're switching platforms, the typeface files may not be identical.

Comment: @Scott I work on Windoze with psd files made by others on Mac and that's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to menu **Edit -> Preferences -> General -> and click the "Reset All Warning Dialogs" button.** Then try to open your psd file again.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options...

- Make your files smaller.
- Get a faster machine.
- Convert some of or all your text to raster. Nothing to update.
- Make sure your fonts are loaded or opened before opening the PSD.
- Save As to make sure your copy of the file is in the most current
  version of Photoshop.

Comment: You can never have too fast of a processor, too big of a hard drive, or too much RAM. :)

Comment: Ancient American proverb...

Comment: @LaurenIpsum this is not an answer to my question. files are made by others, not by be, so I have to keep aligned; a faster machine isn't a imediate future priority; the text shouln't be rastered 'cause it's about web design, where I have to get the styles; the fonts are loaded before opening the psd, otherwise it wouldn't be possible to edit text layers.

Comment: You note above in a comment that these are Mac files being opened on a Windows machine, which you did not state in your original question. Pretty much a guarantee that the fonts have to be translated (updated) in some capacity, and if you'd added that information, I would have mentioned it in my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

In CS4,CS5 go to Preferences > Type and uncheck "Enable missing glyph protection."

Comment: Might work in older versions, but CS4 is the oldest I have.

Comment: did not work. photoshop cs5 still updating text layers automatically when I open the psd file created on mac

Answer (score 0):

Further to Lauren's answer and the comments...  I disagree that "a faster machine isn't an immediate priority".  If you are regularly opening large PSDs that are generated by other versions of Photoshop, and these files regularly cause time-consuming updates when they are opened -- a faster machine is *absolutely* a valid priority.

You may not have other business reasons to support the upgrade investment, but if slow Photoshop is wasting your time...  well, isn't that reason enough?

Comment: in the next six months my boss won't buy me a new machine, so I have to work with this one untill then unfortunately...